# How do I use a json schema to match either empty array or both entries match

Tags: python, format, jsonschema

I'm trying to write a json schema for an optional input. It currently looks like this:

```
"something": {"type": "array",
              "items": {"type": "object",
              "properties": {"text": {"type": "string"},
                             "number": {"type": "integer"}
                            },
                            "additionalProperties": False
                       }
             }
```

This sort of does what I want in that it will accept an empty array and it will accept an array containing a dictionary with "text" and "number". However, I don't want it to accept anything else - e.g. I don't want it to accept an array with only "text" or with only "number" or with any other keys. I want the accepted entries to be either:

```
[]
```

or

```
[{"text": "any text", "number" 5}]
```

(or multiple of these in a list). How can I get this? I tried using dependentRequired but it didn't do anything.

Edit: I've added the additionalProperties parameter so that my schema now won't accept any parameters other than path and size, however, it will still accept just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mostly there.

> I don't want it to accept an array with only "text" or with only "number"

Your schema should already do that. `"type": "object"` in `items` asserts that the items must be objects.

> or with any other keys

You have this right as well with `"additionalProperties": false`.

> my schema now won't accept any parameters other than path and size, however, it will still accept just one of them.

It would accept no properties as well. The `properties` keyword just defines how a property must validate. It doesn't also require that property to be present. If the property isn't there `properties` has nothing to do. You need to also use the `required` keyword to assert that those properties must be present.